# I am having a java lang which it can't start an activity

Tags: java, android

profile fragment
I am Having a java lang exception which can't start activity how can I fix this please help
I am new at this and I need to finish my project today please help

The log cat is below the profile fragment

profile fragment
I am Having a java lang exception which can't start activity how can I fix this please help
I am new at this and I need to finish my project today please help

The log cat is below the profile fragment

```
        private void init(){
    Log.d(TAG, "init: inflating " + getString(R.string.profile_fragment));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.calling_activity))){
        Log.d(TAG, "init: searching for user object attached as intent extra");
        if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.intent_user))){
            User user = intent.getParcelableExtra(getString(R.string.intent_user));
            if(!user.getUser_id().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                Log.d(TAG, "init: inflating view profile");
                ViewProfileFragment fragment = new ViewProfileFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putParcelable(getString(R.string.intent_user),
                        intent.getParcelableExtra(getString(R.string.intent_user)));
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.view_profile_fragment));
                transaction.commit();
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "init: inflating Profile");
                ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = ProfileActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.profile_fragment));
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "init: inflating Profile");
        ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = ProfileActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.profile_fragment));
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

here is the user class

```
      public class User implements Parcelable{

private String user_id;
private long phone_number;
private String email;
private String username;
private String status;

public User(String user_id, long phone_number, String email, String username) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
    this.status = status;

}

public User() {

}


protected User(Parcel in) {
    user_id = in.readString();
    phone_number = in.readLong();
    email = in.readString();
    username = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<User> CREATOR = new Creator<User>() {
    @Override
    public User createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new User(in);
    }

    @Override
    public User[] newArray(int size) {
        return new User[size];
    }
};

public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public long getPhone_number() {
    return phone_number;
}

public void setPhone_number(long phone_number) {
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "user_id='" + user_id + '\'' +
            ", phone_number=" + phone_number +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", username='" + username + '\'' +
            ", status='" + status + '\'' +
            '}';
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(user_id);
    dest.writeLong(phone_number);
    dest.writeString(email);
    dest.writeString(username);
    dest.writeString(status);
}
```

}

logcat

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: umo.com.players, PID: 3876
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{umo.com.players/umo.com.players.Profile.ProfileActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2868)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2958)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1653)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6739)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: 
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2925)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2851)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableArray(Parcel.java:2959)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2808)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3123)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:273)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:226)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:467)
    at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:6971)
    at umo.com.players.Profile.ProfileActivity.init(ProfileActivity.java:92)
    at umo.com.players.Profile.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:83)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7045)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7036)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1217)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2815)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2958) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1653) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6739) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Please add User class code.

Comment: Try to delete the application data or deinstall the app completely and do a fresh install.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the project in your IDE? IntelliJ `Build` => `Rebuild`. Sometimes a dirty cache causes strange problems like this.

Comment: I have  added the user class

Comment: I have rebuild but I still have the same error

Comment: I have deleted the app data and also uninstall but still, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the `status` into constructor:

```
public User(String user_id, long phone_number, String email, String username, String status) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
    this.status = status;

}
```

And add initialization `status`:

```
protected User(Parcel in) {
    user_id = in.readString();
    phone_number = in.readLong();
    email = in.readString();
    username = in.readString();
    status = in.readString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to understand whats going on...

Look at the stack trace...

```java
Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: 
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2925)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2851)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableArray(Parcel.java:2959)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2808)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3123)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:273)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:226)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:467)
    at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:6971)
    at umo.com.players.Profile.ProfileActivity.init(ProfileActivity.java:92)
    at umo.com.players.Profile.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:83)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7045)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7036)
```

Starting at the line lowest down in the stack trace that looks like its relevant to your codebase (hint: look lines starting with your project's package name) :

```
    at umo.com.players.Profile.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:83)
```

You can see some line of code was called in `ProfileActivity` on line `83`. Work your way up the stack. If you understand you push/pop on stacks it makes understanding the rest easier. Try to navigate through the lines in the stack trace and somewhere you'll find the cause of the exception being thrown.